# Create notebook from previously saved python script (v4)

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

While it is no problem to export to and import from python script with v3 notebook format, i have a problem to find a solution to do the same with v4 format . I mean export notebook to python script is an easy win, but it looks like reverse option does not exist. Could anyone push me to the right direction please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've asked developers about this in their Help Chat Room and here is the response:

> no, export is one-way. There are no plans to support roundtrip

I hope it would help someone to save some time.